# How to use #[wasm_bindgen] with a type aliases?

Tags: rust, rust-wasm

What I'd like to do:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub type ParseError = parserange::Error;
```

But the Rust compiler complains:

```
error: #[wasm_bindgen] can only be applied to a function, struct, enum, impl, or extern block
  --> src/lib.rs:89:1
   |
89 | pub type ParseError = parserange::Error;
```

I don't want to add the #[wasm-bindgen] attribute in `parserange.rs` because it's in a separate library that doesn't build with wasm.

Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround is to wrap the `parserange::Error` in a tuple struct to create a new type.  The downside of this is that all functions defined on `parserange::Error` that you'd like to use will have to be redefined to call the error sub-object's function.  This has all the advantages of creating a new type though, such as exporting in through wasm_bindgen, or implementing traits on a type defined in another crate.  More information can be found [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html)